# Is 'we saw that when S+V, at the same time that S+V' grammatically correct?

Tags: parsing, demonstrative

> We saw **that when** Chinese warships turned up off the coast of Alaska,
>   within U.S. territorial waters, **at the same time that** President Obama
>   was on the ground here.

quoted from CNN student news [that can be found here](http://transcripts.cnn.com/TRANSCRIPTS/1509/21/sn.01.html).

The syntax of the sentence above is: 
 
 we saw that when S+V, at the same time that S+V.

Is this grammatically corect?
I thought it should be rather something like 'we saw that when S+V, at the same time, S+V',

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The sentence should be easier to understand if we read the first *that* as "that event".

Comment: "We saw *that*..."  There, **that** is a relative pronoun, referring back to territorial disputes.

Comment: @TRomano: Surely not a **relative** pronoun!

Comment: @ruakh: a demonstrative. Not sure why this morning I read it as introducing the when-clause.  Hmmm...

Comment: @TRomano I made the same mistake. Luckily I noticed before anybody called me on it!

Comment: @StoneyB: and I was already on my second cup of coffee.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's grammatically fine, but awkward because the first *that* is ambiguous. When I first encountered it I took it to be a subordinator (subordinating conjunction), but in fact it's a demonstrative pronoun, pointing to an event which preceded it in the article. The second *that* is a relativizer (relative pronoun), employed in a comparative construction *the same ... that* .

Parse it like this, with stacked adverbials:

```
 We saw that [=that event]
     when Chinese warships turned up   off the coast of Alaska, 
                                       within U.S. territorial waters
                                       at the same time 
                                         that [=as] President Obama was on the ground here.
```

Comment: To help parse, shouldn't the first part have a comma? "We saw that, when..."

Comment: @user151841 That would help, although I generally object to using pointing which does not reflect speech. Moreover, it won't necessarily disambiguate *that*, which can still be parsed as a subordinator. I'd say something like "We saw that *happen* when &c"

Comment: the first "that" is actually referring to *concern*, specifically The US's concern about China's military, rather than an event.

Answer (score 5):

This is ambiguous in writing but completely unambiguous in speech. In the example sentence *that* is a noun phrase, not a subordinator. It is easier to see how the sentence works if we change the word *that*. This word talks about something in the previous sentence. Let's use the word *this*, which works the same way, instead:

- We saw this [when Chinese warships turned up off the coast of Alaska within U.S. territorial waters, at the same time that President Obama was on the ground here].

This sentence is a transcript of a spoken report by a journalist for CNN. When we read the sentence it is easy to think that the word *that* is a subordinator.  Compare the following sentences:

- I saw that yesterday.
- I saw that she had already left.

In the first sentence *that* means *that thing*. In the second sentence the word *that* introduces a new clause. Notice that in the second sentence the verb *SEE* changes its meaning; it means something like *NOTICE* or *UNDERSTAND*.

In the Original Poster's example, the word *that* means *that thing*, it doesn't introduce a new clause. Now, when we *read* the sentence, the word *that* is ambiguous until we get to the end of the sentence and then realise that it cannot be the subordinator. However, this sentence is from a *spoken* report. In the actual speech, this sentence will not be ambiguous.

The reason it won't be ambiguous is that the noun phrase *that* is always stressed and has a full vowel, the same vowel that we find in the word *cat*. The IPA looks like this: /ðæt /. The subordinator *that* is almost *never* stressed and is almost always pronounced /ðət/ with the same vowel that we find at the beginning of the word *America*. We almost never confuse these two words in speech.